# Align item outside of List with items inside the List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, alignment

[image: Image example]

I got the following recycler view, on the view item there are 5 ***checkboxes***. How could I **align** the checkboxes inside the **recycler view** items with the TextView **dates** on the fragment..?

I tried using the same padding, but different dates got different sizes, as well as phones, so it doesnt display a correct alignment on all instances.. Is there a better way? I would appreciate any kind of indication, this is the last problem so I can publish the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a simple way. Take all the textViews of your fragment inside a linear layout group. And keep the **layout_weight** similar. Thus the textViews will be equidistant.

Similarly, take the **checkboxes** in a LinearLayout view group. And keep the **layout_weight** similar. Thus the textViews will be equidistant.

Ps- check the padding and margin of the items, and adjust accordingly.